# Checking Process duration with C

Tags: c, clock, operation, time.h

I am checking process duration with C code.
It works in Windows 32 bits environment, but not in Linux 64bits.

At least my process takes longer than 3 minutes, but it shows 0.062 sec.
My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
clock_t start = clock();

//....... doing something. Sorry:D

printf("%.3f sec\n", (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;
}
```

How to fixed this code to work in 64bits Linux also?
Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't work under Windows either.

Answer (score 2):

The function `clock(3)` doesn't yield the elapsed time:

> The value returned is **the CPU time used so far** as a clock_t.

As the simplest example, if your process sleeps or block for I/O, it won't use much CPU time. If you need to measure actual duration, you could use `time(3)` and `difftime(3)` or maybe `clock_gettime` and the like.

---

Side note: I don't really understand why the code appears to work in Windows, but changing to `time` + `difftime` should work on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [time command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) to get the various time measurements?